# RSpec MustBeConfiguredBeforeExampleGroupsError on plain project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm setting up a Rails 3.1 project and like to properly test it using RSpec.

After running `rails g rspec:install` and further running `rspec`, the console messages read as follows:

```
% rspec
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:470:in `assert_no_example_groups_defined': RSpec's mock_framework configuration option must be configured before any example groups are defined, but you have already defined a group. (RSpec::Core::Configuration::MustBeConfiguredBeforeExampleGroupsError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:168:in `mock_framework='
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:142:in `mock_with'
    from /Users/ened/project/spec/controllers/../spec_helper.rb:19
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/lib/rspec/core.rb:71:in `configure'
    from /Users/ened/project/spec/controllers/../spec_helper.rb:11
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Users/ened/project/spec/controllers/submissions_controller_spec.rb:1
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
    from /usr/bin/rspec:19
```

My `rspec/spec_helper.rb` looks like this:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # == Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.mock_with :rspec

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

I thought it's configured already using the config.mock_with ? I'm puzzled, what is missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just hit this. It turned out to be that some of my old (circa RSpec 1) specs had the following require statement:

```rb
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper')
```

Most of the new specs had this require statement:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'
```

I'd never bothered to tidy up the old style. What this meant was that the spec_helper.rb filename was passed to require in two different ways: one full path, one local path. This in turn caused spec_helper.rb to be executed twice, triggering the error. Changing all the require statements to the short new style fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I just resolved this problem for my Rails app.

My problem was that two spec files were missing the `require 'spec_helper'` line at the top of the file.

Comment: The odd thing is that only 1 out of 6 machines I use had this issue and all were running the build against the same copy from source control.

Comment: exactly the same. The reason is that different OS load files in different order. This way, on some machines the good files where being loaded first, but on some others the first spec loaded was the one missing the 'require' statement...

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem, and my root cause is: 
there are some spec files exist in spec/support folder!

e.g.

```
spec/support/xx_spec.rb
```

which looks like:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe XX do 
...
```

and in the spec/spec_helper.rb file, there are:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

This is a situation that 'spec_helper' was recursive required for unlimited times.

So the solution is very simple:

**REMOVE all the xx_spec.rb files from spec/support folder.**

Answer (score 1):

Could be an issue of `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}`. I have placed it below the config block in my app and it worked.